# How to use modulo in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this raw SQL statement that I would like to use for both Core and ORM:

```
SELECT * FROM `buffet` WHERE `roomId` = '864495034004835' AND `recordMasa` > '1514600000' AND `recordMasa` < '1514900000' AND `recordMasa` mod 10 = 0 LIMIT 0,10000000000;
```

Please do let me know how can I add to my existing code below to include the modulo function:

```
select_statement = select([Buffet]).where(and_(
        Buffet.recordMasa > arguments['startDate'],
        Buffet.recordMasa < arguments['endDate'],
        Buffet.roomId == arguments['ident']
    ))
rooms = conn.execute(select_statement).fetchall()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about [the modulo operato](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)r from python?

```
select_statement = select([Buffet]).where(and_(
        Buffet.recordMasa > arguments['startDate'],
        Buffet.recordMasa < arguments['endDate'],
        Buffet.roomId == arguments['ident'],
        Buffet.recordMasa % 10 == 0,
    ))
```

Comment: Note, this will not work with Postgresql as it will double the % in the query and make %%.

Comment: SQL defines the mod function but Sqlalchemy's `func.mod` does not work against sqlite3, why is that?